# Jquery Full Calendar Events by ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

i am very much stacked to render events by updating my database entry. Initially,
I have successfully rendered events through;

I have event array as:

```
{title: 'Available', start: new Date(2013, m, 05, 09,50), end: new
 Date(2013, m, 05, 10,00), allDay: false},{title: 'Available', start:
 new Date(2013, m, 04, 00,20), end: new Date(2013, m, 04, 00,50),
 allDay: false}
```

Which will be rendered in calander through:

```
events:[<?php echo $events?>]
```

Upto this, **code works good** and renders the event as per required.

After prev, next button is clicked, i have to render the events by updating the database. That is something like this:

```
 $('.fc-button-next span').live('click', function() {
        var calandar = $('#calandar');
         $.ajax({
            url: 'fetchEvents',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(doc) {
                calandar.fullCalendar('removeEvents',event),
               calandar.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent',doc.events);
               calandar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvent',doc.events);
            }
        });
});
```

Where **"fetchEvents"** returns the same event format as before but in JSON form, like:

```
"{title: 'Available', start: new Date(2013, m, 05, 09,50), end: new Date(2013, m, 05, 10,00), allDay: false}"
```

Dont know, how to render JSON event objects on next-click event. That is i have to render completely new events through ajax call. Please suggest.

**Solved:**

Instead of events i have built, i create `JSON` events as suggested by **Lukasz Koziara** as in his first suggestion so that each time calendar event occurs, it acquires the `eventSource` to fetch the events.
JSON EVENT

```
[{"title":"Available","start":"2013-06-06 05:20:00","end":"2013-06-06 05:50:00","allDay":false}]
```

Instead of events, i made a **ajax call** with in `eventSources` to get this type of `JSON EVENTS.`
This looks like:

```
 eventSources: [{
                    url: 'fetchEvents',
                    type: 'POST'
                }]
```

So that, when `calander` renders for the first time or `next`,`previous` or `today` buttons are clicked, `calander` it self fetches events as specified by `eventSources.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion: why not use one type of event source? For example use JSON feed - you can get events range by GET parameters `start` and `end`, so if you change month or view you can send from database appriopriate events.

Second suggestion: if you necessarily need two types of event sources, try use [addEventSource](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) / [removeEventSource](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/)

Comment: Yes, i tried to do so as in your first suggestion as a same eventSources:[{url: 'fetchEvents'}]. But events are not rendering from as specified json format.

Comment: At first check if your fetchEvents function is hit by fullcalendar. If not, point your function without 'url' parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I have edited with what i want with your thoughts.I am gonna check mark your answer for your suggestions.

Comment: If there is one thing I do not understand about fetching events from the server is how the server code will look like in terms of PHP/SQL queries. The code above refers solely to client-side code.